# What's the Cap on Minion Summoning?

Tags: character-creation, powers, summoning, character-levels, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

just screwing around with Character Creation again in **Mutants and Masterminds**. I'm just a little confused with how the Summon power functions, specifically its limits. I know that each attack and effect cannot exceed double the Power Level of the Campaign (combined if its an attack with an effect), Minions cannot exceed my Character's Power Level, each rank in Summon gives you a pool of 15exp to build the minion with, and you have the option to summon multiple copies of minions if you purchase the ability that way.

That being established,

**How many ranks can I have in Summon per level, and would I be able to summon more minions if I sink less experience into each one?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hard limit to the ranks of Summon you can have (unlike the Sidekick Advantage). There are soft limits, based upon your character's available power points / character points and the power level of your minion(s), but those are not hard limits.

The **ONLY** way to summon more than one minion with Summon is the Multiple Minions modifier (which you can take multiple times, each instance doubling the number of summons). It doesn't matter how many unused points your minion build has, you can't summon more than one unique individual without power modifiers. The only way to summon more than one at a time is the Horde modifier. You need both modifiers to summon more minions at once. All summoned minions are the same, and cannot be re-summoned while recovering.

 If you want to summon a large number of cheap minions then you want many instances of Multiple Minions (+2 per Rank of Summon, per instance) and a low Summon rank. Summon 2 with Multiple Minions 8 (+16 per rank) and Horde (+1 per rank) costs 19 points per rank, for 38 total power points; it lets you use a standard action to summon up to 256 Minions (30 power points, identical stats).

If you control additional characters through the Sidekick or Minions Advantages then it is possible to have multiple characters Summon during the same turn. But that's going to be inefficient.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, if you didn't point that out to me, I'd have assumed that I could just try and summon whatever I wanted by using the same power.

Comment: He could, however, create an Array with an assortment of Summon powers with different Ranks and Modifiers attached to let him scale between “1 strong minion” and “lots of weak minions”, with each additional option costing 1 more CP.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what's stated in [ValhallaGH's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154104/whats-the-cap-on-minion-summoning/154107#154107), to be able to summon different types of minions, you need the **Variable Type** extra, possibly two ranks if they really vary a lot.

> **Variable Type**: Minions are normally identical in terms of traits, although they may differ cosmetically. With this modifier you can summon different minions of a general type (like elementals, birds, fish, etc.), or even a broad type (like animals, demons, humanoids, etc.). **General Type: +1 cost per rank. Broad Type: +2 cost per rank**.

As regards your comment that "each attack and effect cannot exceed double the Power Level of the Campaign", it's the same rule as with building PCs, that the combination of attack bonus and effect rank cannot exceed PL, ditto Defense and Toughness.